# How to change an attribute of all form inputs in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, parent, children

I inherit a few forms:

```
<tr>
    <form method="post" action="\">
        <td><input disabled type="text" name="t1" id="t1" value=""></td>
        <td><input disabled type="email" name="t2" id="t2" value=""></td>
        <td><input disabled type="email" name="t3" id="t3" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="submit" id="edit" value="Edit"></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="change" value="Change"></td>
    </form>
</tr>
<tr>
    <form method="post" action="\">
        <td><input disabled type="text" name="t1" id="t1" value=""></td>
        <td><input disabled type="email" name="t2" id="t2" value=""></td>
        <td><input disabled type="email" name="t3" id="t3" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="submit" id="edit" value="Edit"></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="change" value="Change"></td>
    </form>
</tr>
....
```

When I click on an `#edit` button I want to go up the chain to its own `table`, select all `input` children and remove the `disabled` attribute, but only for that form.

I tried something like this:

```
$('#edit').on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this).parent("form");
    // or maybe a $.each ??
    form.children('input').removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this).parent()` is actually a `<td>`, so it returns nothing.

```
$(this).closest('form').find('input').prop('disabled', false);
```

Comment: The reason yours works and his does not is he has edit as the id of multiple elements.

Comment: @marteljn ah .. well you can either update the IDs to be unique (which you *should* do) or use `$("[id=edit]").on('click'` instead

Comment: @Patrioticcow seems to work fine to me except the second row has `iclass`

Comment: @Patrioticcow another issue is that you are binding to the click event on a button of type submit.  Can you change it to a `button` instead?

Comment: made it work. your code is ok, my html rendered a bit wrong. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#edit').on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this).closest("form");
    // or maybe a $.each ??
    form.find('input').attr("disabled","");
});
```

Use `closest` and `find` instead.

`parent` refers to the exact parent whereas `closest` finds the first match up the tree.  `children` are direct children not grand children.

Comment: @Patrioticcow I noticed another issue you have `edit` as an ID more than one time